# White stripe under footer

Tags: html, css, footer

On this site [Link of the site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html) there is a white stripe under the footer. I inspected the element with Firebug, but it shows nothing where this stripe comes from.

This is the complete code HTML: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/YVMteKcp)

This is the complete code CSS: [CSS](http://pastebin.com/Gjw3HtgE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a height on an iframe with the id `f580fdad4` change that from `684px` to `670px`

Edit: the id seems to change: the url is of the iframe is:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=&locale=de_DE&sdk=…Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FRW-Fliesen%2F115860578491339&colorscheme=light

Answer (score 1):

Iframe with Facebook has height set - decrease it and the white stripe goes away. Also height of Iframe set to 100% works fine - at least under Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, upvoted - the question is not easy to resolve for CSS beginners.